# the new iphone SDK 3.2

Tags: iphone

Dose the SDK 3.2 support the iphone as well as the ipad?

dose it support external keypad connecting for the iphone as well?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just download it and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publicly available information on the Apple site says:

> iPhone Developer Program Members can begin developing iPad applications with iPhone SDK 3.2 beta. Registered iPhone Developers can access iPhone SDK 3.1.2 for developing iPhone and iPod touch applications.

The keyboard extensions are in 3.2, for the iPad, not 3.1.2 for the iPhone and iPod touch.

Most 3.2 questions will not be able to be answered as anyone with access to the SDK is also under NDA.

-t